# Translation for angular breadcrumb

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using [ncuiller/angular breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb) for my angular js development. It exposed a directive name **ncy-breadcrumb-last** which can be used as follow.

```
<span ncy-breadcrumb-last></span>
```

I am wondering how could i implement angular translation with this directive as I need to translate the text render by this directive on run time

Full source code: [Click here](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/blob/master/release/angular-breadcrumb.js)

Comment: What did you tried yourself already?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk i were inspecting the source code and seriously i can't find anyway of translating it without modifying the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this open issue on your [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/issues/65) website. There they have good ideas about how to implement this. The one i saw that looks easy to me is using a custom template with some kind of translate fiter.

`{{yourKey | translate}}`
where yourKey is the key for the translation and translate is your custom filter that will use ng-translate or something else

Comment: Hi Jordy, if you inspect carefully the source code, BreadcrumbDirective can have custom template because it is designed to be working in that way. But this is not the case for BreadCrumbLast